# CSS move up / wipe up vertically animation? On scroll?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-animations

I'm working in React js and am trying to emulate the vertical move up animation you see on the text "A DIGITAL DESIGN STUDIO
DRIVEN BY RESEARCH &
STRATEGY" here - https://dashdigital.studio/

[image]

From inspecting this site I have tried working with their translation CSS -

```
transition-delay: .9s;
  transition: transform 1.3s cubic-bezier(.075, .82, .165, 1);
  transform: translateY(0%);
```

However there is the "moving up from behind a wall" effect in use that I can't find a starting point for. Ideally I'd have this occur to elements on scroll - is there a package or starting point for anything like this?

How can I create this vertical wipe from behind a wall effect?

Comment: are you talking about the parallax effect?

Answer (score 0):

You can create **vertically animation** by following this code

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: "Baloo Paaji", cursive;
  background: #1e90ff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 220px;
  position: relative;
}

h1, h2 {
  font-size: 75px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
h1 span, h2 span {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 80%);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 80%);
  transform: translateY(-150px);
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation-name: titleAnimation;
          animation-name: titleAnimation;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
          animation-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
          animation-duration: 3s;
}

h1 span {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
          animation-delay: 0.6s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
h1 span:first-child {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.7s;
          animation-delay: 0.7s;
}
h1 span:last-child {
  color: #ffe221;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
          animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

h2 {
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
h2 span {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4.1s;
          animation-delay: 4.1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
h2 span:first-child {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4.2s;
          animation-delay: 4.2s;
}
h2 span:last-child {
  color: #ffe221;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
          animation-delay: 4s;
}

.usechrome {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: helvetica, arial;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes titleAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-50px);
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 80%);
    clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 80%);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 15%);
    clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 15%);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 15%);
    clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 15%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(50px);
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 0%, 0 100%, 0 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 0%, 0 100%, 0 100%);
  }
}

@keyframes titleAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-50px);
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 80%);
    clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 80%);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 15%);
    clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 15%);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 15%);
    clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 15%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(50px);
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 0%, 0 100%, 0 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 0%, 0 100%, 0 100%);
  }
}/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
```

```html
   <section class="container">
      <h1 class="title">
        <span>Hi, nice</span>
        <span>to see</span>
        <span>you here</span>
      </h1>
      
      <h2 class="title">
        <span>This is</span>
        <span>a long</span>
        <span>sub title</span>
        
        
      </h2>
    </section>
    <span class="usechrome">Use Chrome for a better experience</span>
```

Comment: It looks like your titles come out of a diagonal clip path. Can you make it straight horizontal?